# add class on hover is glitchy on chrome, works fine on firefox though

Tags: javascript, css

Please take a look at this page here :

http://www.pragyan.org/15/home/events/

if opened in firefox works quite well, while in chrome it doesn't work that smooth. I have no idea what is causing this issue,

the code responsible for adding the effect is :

```
$('.cluster-section').hover(function(){
            var item=$(this).parent().attr('id');
            menu=state_define[item];
            index=index_define[item];
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });
```

to refer the full code:

http://www.pragyan.org/15/cms/templates/space_events/scripts/main.js

Answer (score 1):

add

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to the animated elements.